# Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError when implementing firebase cloud messaging

Tags: java, c#, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-manifest

I am implementing push notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging, for this I added this code in my AndroidManifest.xml file

```xml
<!--FCM RECEIVER-->
<receiver
  android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
  android:exported="false"/>
<receiver
  android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
  android:exported="true"
  android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
    <category android:name="${applicationId}"/>
  </intent-filter>    
</receiver>
<!---FCM RECEIVER ENDS HERE-->
```

but when I try to run the application, it throws the application even before starting the activity

```
Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 'Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/datatransport/runtime/dagger/internal/Factory;'
```

By the way, I had Installed two NuGet Packages for this functionality:

1. Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base
2. Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging

I have tried:

1. deleting the bin and obj folder and building the solution again
2. updating all the same family nugget packages to the same version

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Installing the Xamarin.Google.Dagger package solved this problem for me.

Comment: How did you find that the error related to the missing package?

Comment: I wish this was mentioned in the [Xamarin doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm)!

Comment: Such an easy solution. I wish more problems were solved like this.

Comment: Make sure you install it into the android project, and not the xamarin forms project.

Comment: Please update answer to specify install must be on the Android Project

Answer (score 8):

Just Install the package Xamarin.Google.Dagger. That should do the trick. Seems it's trying to look for the package but doesn't find it.